# Titanium button listener to custom function

Tags: function, button, titanium, listener

I am creating a simple app to rotate an image using a textfield and a button. (No alloy used)

When I catch the event on the eventListener, I want to use two custom functions, but I get a weird error.

The code is as follows

```
    Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title: "App Rotation",
    backgroundColor : 'orange'
});


// Create a TextField.
var textField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    height : 35,
    top : 10,
    left : 40,
    width : 240
});

win1.add(textField);

// Create an ImageView.
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : 'appceleratorIcon.png',
});
// Add to the parent view.
win1.add(image);

var current_degrees = 0;

// Create a Button.
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Rotate Image',
    top : '70%',
    left : '30%'
});

// Listen for click events.
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var txtfield_value = textField.value;
    var dialog_text;
    var dialog_title;

    if (txtfield_value >= -90 && txtfield_value <= 90) {

         current_degrees = rotate_degrees(current_degrees, txtfield_value);
        dialog_text = "Rotated " + txtfield_value;
        dialog_title = "Rotation completed";

    } else {

        dialog_text = "Type between -90 and 90";
        dialog_title = "Error!";

    }
     show_dialog(dialog_text, dialog_title);
});

// Add to the parent view.
win1.add(button);

function rotate_degrees(new_degrees, old_degrees) {

    var matrix2d = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().rotate(new_degrees);
    img.transform = matrix2d;

    return (parseInt(new_degrees) + parseInt(old_degrees));
}

win1.open();

function show_dialog (dialog_text, dialog_title) {
    var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
    message: dialog_text,
    ok: 'Continue',
    title: dialog_title
  });
  dialog.show();
}
```

And the error is the following:

```
[ERROR] :  ReferenceError: anium is not defined
[ERROR] :  File: app.js
[ERROR] :  Line: undefined
[ERROR] :  SourceId: undefined
[ERROR] :  Backtrace:
[ERROR] :  undefined
```

I have tried commenting codes, and the only time this error will not appear is when I comment both custom functions.

Is this the way to code custom functions so that when a button is called I can execute my function so that the program stays 'clean' and not dirty with code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

'anium' is not defined looks like a typo somewhere else. Just search for it perhaps you find some space between "Tit anium" somewhere.

Also you have a function dialog_title but are creating a local variable with the same name and want to use the function inside the button eventlistener.